# I'm trying to open a repo from codesandbox in vscode and I'm getting an ssh connection error

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, openssh, codesandbox

This is what I'm getting in output terminal. I have tested a few things gleaned from the web but nothing has worked so far.

`Failed to connect to the remote extension host server`

Log:

```
[15:50:13.256] Log Level: 2
[15:50:13.262] remote-ssh@0.70.0[15:50:13.262] win32 x64
[15:50:13.294] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb", attempt 1
[15:50:13.294] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[15:50:13.295] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[15:50:13.295] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"rohithreddy20.kimnganle.master.csb":"linux","rohithreddy20.swoop.draft---cold-currying.csb":"linux"}
[15:50:13.296] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[15:50:13.296] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined[15:50:13.296] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:50:13.297] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[15:50:13.297] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:50:13.297] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": true
[15:50:13.297] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[15:50:13.298] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": ["gitpod.gitpod-remote-ssh"][15:50:13.298] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:50:13.298] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}[15:50:13.299] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[15:50:13.299] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[15:50:13.300] SSH Resolver called for host: rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb[15:50:13.301] Setting up SSH remote "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb"[15:50:13.343] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[15:50:13.350] Install and start server if needed
[15:50:15.585] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[15:50:15.631] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
[15:50:15.640] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 63679 "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb" bash
[15:50:15.644] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:50:21.365] > ssh: connect to host 167.235.6.182 port 19550: Connection refused

The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.]0;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:50:21.366] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[15:50:22.666] "install" terminal command done
[15:50:22.667] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:50:22.667] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:50:22.668] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[15:50:22.669] Resolver error: Error:at h.Create (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430425)at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:429068)at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:524212)at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487216at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)at async t.resolve (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[15:50:22.679] ------
[15:50:22.735] ------
[15:50:22.735] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb", attempt 2, (Reconnection)
[15:50:22.736] SSH Resolver called for host: rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb
[15:50:22.737] Setting up SSH remote "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb"
[15:50:22.742] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server[15:50:22.752] Install and start server if needed
[15:50:44.751] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[15:50:44.752] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceledat h.Canceled (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430621)at c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487128at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)at async t.resolve (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[15:50:44.756] ------
[15:50:44.763] ------
[15:50:44.763] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb", attempt 3, (Reconnection)
[15:50:44.764] SSH Resolver called for host: rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb
[15:50:44.764] Setting up SSH remote "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb"
[15:50:44.767] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[15:50:44.770] Install and start server if needed
[15:51:27.449] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[15:51:27.450] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceledat h.Canceled (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430621)at c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487128at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)at async t.resolve (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[15:51:27.456] ------
[15:51:27.485] ------
[15:51:27.485] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb", attempt 4, (Reconnection)
[15:51:27.485] SSH Resolver called for host: rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb
[15:51:27.485] Setting up SSH remote "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb"
[15:51:27.489] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server[15:51:27.493] Install and start server if needed
[15:51:29.043] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[15:51:29.044] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceledat h.Canceled (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430621)at c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487128at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)at async t.resolve (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[15:51:29.048] ------
[15:51:29.053] ------
[15:51:29.054] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb", attempt 5, (Reconnection)
[15:51:29.054] SSH Resolver called for host: rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb
[15:51:29.054] Setting up SSH remote "rohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb"
[15:51:29.057] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[15:51:29.060] Install and start server if needed
[15:51:29.612] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[15:51:29.613] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceledat h.Canceled (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430621)at c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487128at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)at async t.resolve (c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)at async c:\Users\rohit.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[15:51:29.617] ------
ERR [attempt 1] resolveAuthority(ssh-remote) returned an error after 9444 ms CodeExpectedErrorat I._resolveAuthority (workbench.desktop.main.js:3224:7184)at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async I._resolveAuthorityInitial (workbench.desktop.main.js:3224:7788)at async I._scanAndHandleExtensions (workbench.desktop.main.js:3224:9623)at async I._initialize (workbench.desktop.main.js:3222:24421)
ERR ENOPRO: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote%2Brohithreddy20.swoop.csb-e5lqzo---draft---awesome-glade.csb/project/swoop'at u.withProvider (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/rohit/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:608:14059)at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async u.doWatch (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/rohit/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:608:27826)at async vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/rohit/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:608:27692`
```

I tried for hours to solve this problem but couldn't do it
Could someone help me on the reason for the problem or on a possible solution?

Comment: you want to see the repo on codesandbox as a virtual workspace? Do you have a FileSystem extension that interfaces to that virtual file system?

Comment: Yes, I want to see it as virtual workspace. what is this filesystem extension?

Comment: you have to find or write the FileSystem extension that implements the communication, for example there is an extension that allows you to use an ftp site as a file system

Comment: There is an extension which shows the contents of the repo if the connection is successful